# In App Purchase sandbox not prompting for my login/pass

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We're developing an app which (ofcourse) uses in app purchases (IAP).
I've done everything in the guide to enable iap and everything works fine, untill I want to make purchase.
Some of the code:

**MainViewController.m**

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
            if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
                    MyStoreObserver *observer = [[MyStoreObserver alloc] init];     
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];        

                    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObjects: @"com.company.app.product1", @"com.company.app.product1", nil]];
                    request.delegate = self;
                    [request start];
            }
    };

    -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
            for (SKProduct *prod in response.products) {
                    NSLog(@"%@ (%@)", prod.localizedTitle, prod.price);
            }
            [request release];
    };

    -(IBAction)clickBuy:(UIButton *)__sender {
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.company.app.product1"];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    };
```

**MyStoreObserver.m**

```
    - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                    NSLog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased");
                    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:               
                    NSLog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed");
                    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                    NSLog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored");
                    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                    NSLog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing");
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

The `productRequest:` delegate method shows 2 products with their name / price. Like I entered in the iTunes connect site.

But once I click the 'buy' button, no dialog pops up or asks me for my credentials. Only "SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing" is logged.
And I:
- ... have logged out in the settings/store pane
- ... am using the right provisioning profiles
- ... am desperate

Anyone?

Comment: Yesterday my in-app purchasing worked fine(with code similar to yours). I got the buy-now popup box appearing just fine, but testing this morning I get the same thing as you. It recognizes my product(I can get the name description, price, product ID ect...) but when I set the payment and add the payment in my "purchaseUpgrade" function nothing happens. I'm wondering if there's an issue with the sandbox right now... are other people able to test their in-app purchases properly at the moment?

Comment: I hope this is the case, read the official guide 4 times and followed it through... But still no dialog.

Comment: it should work now, just tried.

Comment: You're right, would seem like apple had some troubles with the sandbox server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: happens with me also. Does this happen to SandBox only?

Answer (score 13):

I encountered a similar problem, but mine was more of a boneheaded move on my part. I had 'refactored' the call to `finishTransaction` so that it was being called for every state in `transactionState`:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                // do stuff
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // do stuff
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                // do stuff
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}
```

Turns out™, this will also call `finishTransaction` on `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`, which will cause a crash. Moving `finishTransaction` back into each case of the switch statement fixed that.

Answer (score 5):

After Pulling my hair out in frustration with a similar problem (instead of not being asked for my credentials it was automatically filling in the email address without the option to change it even when logged out of the store in the settings app). I discovered that I had a failed transaction stuck in the queue from development builds on the same device, I had to clear all of the transactions in the queue on the device and then try to test again.

```
NSArray *transactions = [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions];
for(id transaction in transactions){
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

I hooked this code upto an IBOutlet and after being run once my in app purchases worked.

Comment: On my first click my payment queue is empty, the second click throws an `NSInvalidArgumentException: Cannot finish a purchasing transaction`. Which makes sense, since in the first click I added an item into the queue, but no dialog shows...

Comment: I have the same issue on my development build. I tried using the above code to clear out failed transactions, but the SKPaymentQueue has none. But I still get a dialog asking for credentials from previous test user accounts (even if I have logged out of an account in the settings). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I also had been pulling my hair out a bit with this.  Turns out a simple reboot of the test device got everything working fine.

Comment: This is worth more than a thumb up :-)

Comment: Still relevant 10 years later.. :)

Answer (score 2):

**An iPhone can be restricted from accessing the Apple App Store**. For example, parents can restrict their children’s ability to purchase additional content.

Before placing transaction make sure, can you u buy or not?Check it like this -

```
  -(IBAction)clickBuy:(UIButton *)__sender {

      if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"Product_id"];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
      }
      else {
      //show appropriate message 
      }
   }
```

Comment: I'm checking the `[SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]` when fetching the products, and (like I said) it shows me the 2 products I entered, so i  `can` make payments on this device.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on iPhone/iPad Simulator 4.2 or something? That might be the problem. Testing on iPhone/iPad Simulator 5.0, or the device, will run storekit correctly.

Comment: I spent hours working on this. I eventually got it to work with a sandbox users but first I had to delete the sandbox users i was using, create a new yahoo mail account, sign up that users with an Apple ID, verify that Apple ID in my email, go back to my iPhone, login with that Apple ID to the iTunes store, and purchase through it. Finally after all that it worked and I'm submitting my app to the app store.