# SKPaymentQueue addPayment doesn't always trigger native confirm dialog

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

Ok, I'm implementing IAP into an iOs app and only some products in the store actually trigger the native purchase handling dialogs.

**Background:**

The app uses cocos2dx with javascript bindings for cross-platformability. We're dipping into the iOs native sectors to implement the store handling.

These calls all work correctly:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
```

A note on the last one. All product ids are checked and return as valid in the `productsRequest:request didReceiveResponse:response` callback but only if I don't include the bundle id in the identifiers that get sent. Most examples I saw said this was needed, but if included they all return as `invalidProductIdentifiers`. Could this be indicative of a problem?

So currently **some** products bring up the native purchase confirm dialog after their (previously verified) ids are passed to `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]`. Most of them simply do nothing afterwards. No callback on `paymentQueue:queue updatedTransactions:transactions`, no error code, no crash.

I can't see a pattern for why some work and most don't. At least one consumable, non-consumable and subscription work, so I don't think it's that. I found that if I break and step through the code pausing after `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]`, there's a small chance a few products work more often, although it's not consistent. This lead me to think it may be a threading issue, but you can see what I've tried below and it didn't help.

**Things I've tried:**

Reading around [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008636/inapp-purchase-skpaymentqueue-finish-transaction-doesnt-work) and elsewhere, people suggested [changing test users](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1262697), [clearing the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910631/in-app-purchase-sandbox-not-prompting-for-my-login-pass) with `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]`, and that Apple's Sandbox server sometimes 'has issues'. But none of this fixed it, and it strikes me as odd that I'm not getting crashes or errors, it just doesn't react at all to certain product ids.

Here's the actual call with some things I've tried:

```
- (void)purchaseProductWithId:(const char*)item_code
{
   /** OCCASIONALLY MAY NEED TO CLEAR THE QUEUE **
   NSArray *transactions = [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions];
   for(id transaction in transactions){
      [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
   }// */

// dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
      SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:item_code]];
//    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addPayment:) withObject:payment waitUntilDone:NO];
      [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
// } );
}
```

If there's any other code that could be useful let me know.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**
I've added the `hasAddObserver` check from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008636/inapp-purchase-skpaymentqueue-finish-transaction-doesnt-work?rq=1) question and that's not the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a temporary thing. I'd hate to accuse Apple's sandbox servers of being flaky, but nothing was changed and then days later it suddenly worked.

So if you have a similar issue maybe take a break and come back to it later?